# Filter rows based on criteria from another file or sheet

Tags: excel, function, filter, spreadsheet

I have a large data spreadsheet containing 2 columns. First column are SKUs and second a list of associated images to that SKU.

I also have another spreadsheet containing one column with images that need to be remove from the main list.

On the main spreadsheet if there are several images for that row and it contains an image that needs to be removed, I only want to remove that image and not the entire row.

In addition, I need to remove all the rows (on the main spreadsheet still) that the criteria (spreadsheet 2) didnt find any matches.

See attached image for a visual representation.

[image]

Thank you all for any input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this formula for you. Let, give it a try-

```
=FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A6,BYROW(B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(x,,","),tt,COUNTIFS(F2:F4,t),TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(t,tt=0,"")))))),
BYROW(B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(x,,","),tt,COUNTIFS(F2:F4,t)>0,OR(tt)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow brilliant! Seems to be working really well. Tested on 2 spreadsheets and so far so good. May I ask (if you can) to break for me what each part of the formula is doing? And also the functions you are using (HSTACK, BYROW, etc, etc). Thanks again!!